# Crystal Report needs to eliminate page number when generate CSV only

Tags: csv, crystal-reports, page-numbering

I want to eliminate page number value from the report only when tries to generate CSV file. But also we need that page number display when tries to generate pdf. Can  anyone help me through this.

Crystal Report Verion:13.0.2000.0

Comment: Does anyone export to both csv and pdf in a single run of the report?

Comment: No, run will be different. But its uses the same rpt file.

Answer (score 0):

One option you could use to achieve this would be to create a parameter fields that asks the user if they want page numbers on the report each time the report is run.  You can also include text that helps indicate not having page numbers is recommended for CSV file exports of the report.

The parameter field should provide an option for the user to choose Yes or No.  You can default the answer to one of the two values to help speed up parameter value selection at run-time.

Then you use this parameter to control the Suppress property of the page number fields.

If you need help with setting up the parameter or the formula for the Suppress property, let me know in a comment and I can update this answer with more detail.